# How can I control the plugins loading order in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-earth-engine-python-api

I created a QGIS plugin that use Google Earth Engine (GEE) python library. The simplest way to use GEE python library in QGIS is by using the GEE plugin.

To be loaded properly, my plugin needs that the Google Earth Engine plugin is loaded first to have access to the ee library.

How can I control the plugins loading order?

Comment: Hi, I don't know the answer but a suggestion: Be flexible and allow your plugin to load without the other plugin requirement. Try to defer actions requiring the other plugin until a user intervention and check there whether the other plugin is loaded.

Comment: look at how the GEE plugin loads the library and copy that?